# Storage to store vectors of int(On disk matrix storage)

Tags: c#, database, vector, large-data

I have some int vectors of same length(or just matrix) and I need to store them in some kind of DB, because now I just store them in .txt file.

1. I need ability to extend matrix by appending rows to end of matrix and I need const time for that operation(not depending on size of matrix).
2. It wiil be good if it can handle large data and don't load whole dataset in memory.

Comment: did you consider to use some nosql db?

Comment: Can you elaborate here "some kind of DB"

Comment: @FelicePollano I don't know much about databases, I just need storage for my matrix.

Comment: @mrgloom any db can do what you want. But maybe for you just serailizing the structure would suffice